# How to sum alias value if they are on same date and id?

Tags: mysql

I want to add the values in the column percent if the department_id value are same in the same date.

Here is the query that I try,

```
SELECT DATE(r.date) as date, 
       d.department_id, 
       ( ( select COUNT(case when correct='yes' then 1 END) )/100 * (select count(id) from tbl_quest) ) as percent 
FROM   tbl_show r 
LEFT JOIN  get_admin a ON (r.get_admin_id = a.admin_id) 
LEFT JOIN get_department d on (a.department_id = d.department_id) 
GROUP by r.date
```

Here is the result of above query:

```
date        department_id   percent     
2015-11-17  3               0.1000
2015-11-17  1               0.5700
2015-11-17  3               0.2000
2015-11-18  1               0.5700
2015-11-18  1               0.0100
........
```

Now, I want to sum percent value if that values are same department id and same date.

I want to change like the following result,

```
date        department_id   percent     
2015-11-17  3               0.3000
2015-11-17  1               0.5700
2015-11-18  1               0.5800
........
```

I very appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: Can you show us sample input data?  If not, we are going to have to back out your original tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use group by on **date** & **department_id** and select SUM(percent).

Comment: Please can you show sample code, because I'm a newbie in sql.

Comment: Try with this.......



`SELECT DATE(r.date) as date, 
       d.department_id, 
       ( ( select COUNT(case when correct='yes' then 1 END) )/100 * (select count(id) from tbl_quest) ) as percent ,
  SUM(percent) as total_percent
FROM   tbl_show r 
LEFT JOIN  get_admin a ON (r.get_admin_id = a.admin_id) 
LEFT JOIN get_department d on (a.department_id = d.department_id) 
GROUP by r.date, d.department_id`

Comment: When I try as you said, it show `Unknown column 'percent' in 'field list'` error.  I think it because of this line `SUM(percent) as total_percent`.

Comment: Ok Try again with this:

`SELECT temp.date, temp.department_id, SUM(temp.percent) AS total_percent FROM ( SELECT DATE(r.date) as date, 
          d.department_id, 
          ( ( select COUNT(case when correct='yes' then 1 END) )/100 * (select count(id) from tbl_quest) ) as percent   
                FROM   tbl_show r 
                LEFT JOIN  get_admin a ON (r.get_admin_id = a.admin_id) 
                LEFT JOIN get_department d on (a.department_id = d.department_id) 
                GROUP by r.date, d.department_id
               ) AS temp`

Comment: Its show only one record like this `2015-11-17   3  0.3000`. How can I get the next day and different department id on same day?